# How to unroll client side bundle

Tags: gulp

On these days, a good approach to obtain a great performance in SPA application is prepare a gzipped client side bundle from a few gulp tasks.

Based on these, an awful approach to debug is consider the use of a full bundle unminified @ dev environment. The question is about possible of use a gulp browserify task and gulp inject to unroll the client bundle in separated files like was developed.

I mean, maybe would be possible inject a bundle or a couple of files with a browserify boilerplate to resolve a bunch of `require`'s and `module.exports` statements.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is use an option that gulp-browserify provides to run a complete src tree instead use a bundle. just set a optional flag `debug: true` as follows, in example:

```
gulp.src('./app/js/app.js'). // this path is the entry point
    pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals: true,
        debug: true
    }));
```